# Zebra printer KR403 port number

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

I try to print to zebra printer.
Zebra provided me a standard code sample in C#
There they used port 9100 to connect to the printer

```
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();

    client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9100);
```

However each time i run this code it crashes as there is no such port number available
I also used telnet 127.0.01 9100 and that confirmed that there is nothing listening to 9100
I also tried port 6101 as used by some Zebra printers no success either.

I can run in a dos command

```
    print /D:\\127.0.0.1\KR403 d:\print.txt
```

This does print, and proves it listens somehow to network
Internally. This device is a USB printer, and that's making it complex to set a static port ID. Perhaps also strange the above command does print a barcode, but doesnt cut the paper; when i print using notepad (which i assume does not use the network to print) then it cuts paper but the paper is 40cm long (way to large).. so i am in driver battle it seams.

What i hope to do, is send a print command using C# and use ZPL commands to print
Microsoft wrote an article about raw printing too, but it fails on this printer.

All i want to do is send ZPL instructions to this printer.
Aslo tried generic txt driver, this works for notepad but not for C#

Code used :

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   // print /D:\\127.0.0.1\KR403 d:\print.txt


  namespace PrinterTest
  {
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Printer IP Address and communication port
        string ipAddress = @"192.168.2.109";
        int port = 6101; // 9100;//

        // ZPL Command(s)
        string ZPLString =
            "^XA" +
            "^FO50,50" +
            "^A0N50,50" +
            "^FDHello, World!^FS" +
            "^XZ";

        try
        {
            // Open connection
            System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
            //client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
           client.Connect(ipAddress, port);
           // string tmp = "\\127.0.0.1\KR403";
           // client.Connect(@"\\localhost",9100);



            // Write ZPL String to connection
            System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            writer.Write(ZPLString);
            writer.Flush();

            // Close Connection
            writer.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
    }

  }
  }
```

Comment: is the printer installed on your machine? Printer settings should show the port it's connected with in your control panel.

Comment: Yes it is, but where it normally would read a port nummber, i see USB0001 not something i can use.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `TcpClient` to connect to a locally attached device like USB. TcpClient is for network devices.  If you put your printer on your network, then you can use `TcpClient`.

Comment: The printer was shared
A little proof for it the DOS Print command worked only when using the share name of the printer.. 
However no port number got revealed /(and i tried a lot more)

Comment: This is the correct answer for your actual question.  You can't use a netowrk connection to send to a locally connected device.  If you had the printer on the network instead, you could swap 127.0.0.1 (localhost) out for the hostname or IP address of the printer and you would be most of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after some mental meltdowns (not joking there)
As I've been trying all day to get this printer to work.
I finally managed to print to this printer using a RawPrinterHelper, 
And I also fixed a small bug in that helper too.

I'm happy to share it, but not sure how to share a small visual studio 10 project
If anyone knows how to do that here, i post it.

My code can now print to a local USB printer and without a dialog too / and i can cut paper.

(please just comment me on how to post a prj)

Answer (score 0):

A work around for these cases is to share the usb printer and then map the LTP port to the resource with the net use command

```
NET USE LPT1: \\[computer_ip]\[printer_sharname] /PERSISTENT:YES
```

then with your application you can write the string directly to the LTP1 port and it will print.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we reverse engineered the signaling, wrote a raw USB driver for it and then used zebra markup language to print. This is deeply nested within other code, and sadly I cannot share it.

That language by itself is also something that's not that fine to work with.
You need to think about buffers states handling error codes, and printers stopping responding, you will need some keep a live check - etc etc.

So if you can make use of Windows drivers, and your printer is not critical try that, else write your own raw driver, and learn to understand all binary error codes, and keep in mind that printers even with big names still jam easily, so for me if I had the choice, I'd say abandon this printer, or else be prepared for a big project with a few nightmares. It'll cost you a few weeks if you have to start from scratch.